# warning C code (connection to Mysql db)

Tags: mysql, c

I get some annoying warnings while trying to connect to a Mysql db.

Here's the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* host = "localhost";
char *database="Dbis_RG";
char user_name[10];
char passwd[10];

MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES* result;
MYSQL_FIELD* field;

int main ()
{

    system("clear");


    printf("Insert yur user name: \n");
    scanf("%s", &user_name);

    printf("Insert your passwd: \n");
    scanf("%s", &passwd);


    MYSQL *conn;

   conn = mysql_init(NULL);


    /* Connection to database */
      if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, host,
            user_name, passwd, database, 0, NULL,CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            } 



        printf ("Connection successful.\n");


}
```

As a matter of fact I get these warnings, but I don't see how I could get rid of them:

```
1.0.c: In function ‘main’:
1.0.c:23: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’
1.0.c:26: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’
```

Thank you very much

Mauro

Comment: Hello @Mauro ! We are so excited that you are participating in Stack Overflow. However, we've noticed that you have asked us several questions in the past but have not accepted any answers. **Will you go back and accept some answers to your previous questions?** You can do this by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
scanf("%s", user_name);
scanf("%s", passwd);
```

But it's not a good idea. Use `fgets` instead. Check your manual page. And for further details, try to make people motivated to answer your questions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It actually works, but you say that's not a good idea..does that mean it's not ansi C?..If I use fgets does that solve the problem the same way? thanks

Comment: @Mauro -- please read what @ Tomer already said and fix your mistake! He didn't say it wasn't ansi C; he said what you wrote was a security hole and was dangerous.

Comment: also, if you don't want to use fgets, you can limit the # of bytes scanf reads by doing %9s (no space) or %9c (with space) to read only 9 characters, so scanf("%9s", user_name);

Answer (score 2):

1. What brain said.
2. You're using `scanf()` in a non-safe way - if my name is more than 10 characters long (or if I just want to break your program) the `scanf()` call will overflow beyond the array. Use `scanf("%9s", user_name);` instead (I think you need to leave room for the `'\0'` at the end).

Answer (score 0):

username and passwd are already arrays, so you should get rid of the "&" when using scanf.

Comment: Call them what you want. They are memory addresses :)

Comment: @brain: you should read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/). And once you're there, read the other sections too :P

Comment: @pmg: The point is the function expects a pointer, and that's what it gets in that respect. Even if the argument passed is an array. Now, changed my answer as not to confuse people. :p

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by using strlen...I check the input through strlen and if it's greater than the specified array size a suitable warning prevents the user to carry on...Do you think it's a good idea ?

Comment: No! After the scanf, if more characters were read than the space reserved for them, the harm is already done. You cannot undo the harm with a warning.